# How to implement htmleditor in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I like implement htmleditor in xamarin forms, I have found one package like TEditor and TEditor.VK. Both are not giving a xaml code, Please provide link for htmleditor or else give me a suggestion to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could download the source file from from the GitHub.
https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/TEditor

It provide a code sample with c# `TEditorHtmlView`. https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/TEditor/blob/master/Sample/TEditor.Forms.Sample/TEditorHtmlView.cs

You could check the xaml below.

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button
            Clicked="Button_Clicked"
            HeightRequest="100"
            Text="HTML Editor" />
        <WebView x:Name="_displayWebView" HeightRequest="500" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
 async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await ShowTEditor();
    }
    async Task ShowTEditor()
    {
        TEditorResponse response = await CrossTEditor.Current.ShowTEditor("<!-- This is an HTML comment --><p>This is a test of the <strong style=\"font-size:20px\">TEditor</strong> by <a title=\"XAM consulting\" href=\"http://www.xam-consulting.com\">XAM consulting</a></p>");
        if (response.IsSave)
        {
            if (response.HTML != null)
            {
                _displayWebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource() { Html = response.HTML };
            }
        }
    }
```